# I want to know why the string d is getting abce after abcg0 as its size is only 5

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to know why the string `d` is getting abce after abcg0 as its size is only 5. What is the reason? Please help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[] = "abcd";
    char b[50] = "abce";
    char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'f'};
    char d[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', '0'};
    printf("%s",d);}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the editor & apply code formatting. Do not post text as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid C and will result in undefined behavior.

This is because your first two strings (`a` and `b`) are null-terminated, whereas your last two strings (`c` and `d`) are not.

When you initialize strings using double-quotes (as in the first two cases -- `a` and `b`), the string is null-terminated automatically for you.

If you initialize the string as an array (as in the last 2 cases -- `c` and `d`), it is not null-terminated. You have to null-terminate it yourself.

In C, the null character is represented as `'\0'`.

Hence, in the case of the `c` and `d` variables, the valid initializations would be:

```
char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'f', '\0'};
char d[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', '\0'};
```

**Alternative:**

Its also possible to initialize like this:

```
char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 0};
char d[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 0};
```

In this case, the strings will also be null-terminated. This works since 0 is the ASCII code for the null character `\0`.

**This is the reason *why* you observe the output "abcg0abce":**

Even though the code is invalid, the `printf` will try to print out the string you told it to (But, `%s` relies on the string being null-terminated!) In doing so, it continues to print out character by character until it reaches the first occurrence of `'\0'` in memory. In your case, the string `b` happened to be placed next to the string `d` in memory -- hence, this is what gets printed. However, this is not guaranteed to happen and its very easy to change that behavior by adjusting the compilation flags.

Answer (score 0):

In the array of caracter ,you should add this caracter '\0'

The length of the array does not affect the length of the string, when you print the string, printf prints the string character by character until the last character before '\0' (printf does not print '\ 0')

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[] = "abcd";
    char b[50] = "abce";
    char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'f','\0'};
    char d[10] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'g', '0','\0'};
    printf("%s\n",d);
}
```